# How to not get all the data of a json call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I can get all the data from my database using this code. What i want is that it only selects 5 items, so i can use a get more button to show another 5 items.

This code gets all the items.

```
    $.ajax({
  url: 'getFeed.php',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
  timeout: 5000,
  success: function(data, status){

    $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
      var upload = item.id;

      output.append(upload);
    });
  },
  error: function(){
    output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
  }
});
```

returns
`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

How can i get

`1 2 3 4 5`

?

Thank you

Comment: Use a counter? Did you try that?

Comment: That would generally be something you do on the serverside, sending a `skip` and `limit` in the ajax request, and then structuring the query to the DB based on that

Comment: Ya, this ***must*** be handled server side

Answer (score 0):

If it's a permanent hard limit at 5 you could do something like

```
$.each(data, function(i,item){ 
  var upload = item.id;

  if (i < 5) output.append(upload);
});
```

Only appending if the index variable is less that 5 (on a 0 index, anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to limit the result from your database. I couldn't help but notice the use of JSONP, which is perfect if you are retrieving results from another server/subdomain(probably not managed by you); in this case I'm guessing the API provider has a limit function that you could send with the url.
Check the documentation for the db you're using.